# Removing strings in several files inside folder and all subfolders

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder with bunch of subfolders that contains `*.qc` files with different names (`ump.qc`, `ak.qc`, `m4.qc`, etc...). Now I need to remove certain entire strings from all of those `.qc` files that starts with `$hbox`. For example

Current version

```
// 2 attachment(s)
$attachment 0 "Weapon" 0.000000 -38.600000 1.000000
$attachment 1 "Weapon" 0.000000 1.000000 2.000000

// 46 hit box(es)
$hbox 0 "L UpperArm" -20.781071 -5.960000 -7.010000 2.890000 6.380000 3.900000
$hbox 0 "L Forearm" -17.050846 0.000000 -3.820000 1.040000 3.630000 2.280000
$hbox 0 "L Hand" -7.200000 -1.960000 -3.630000 0.150000 2.380000 2.870000
$sequence "idle1" "idle1" fps 1
$sequence "idle2" "idle2" fps 1
$sequence "idle3" "idle3" fps 1
```

Needed version

```
// 2 attachment(s)
$attachment 0 "Weapon" 0.000000 -38.600000 1.000000
$attachment 1 "Weapon" 0.000000 1.000000 2.000000

// 46 hit box(es)
$sequence "idle1" "idle1" fps 1
$sequence "idle2" "idle2" fps 1
$sequence "idle3" "idle3" fps 1
```

As you can see, the strings begin the same way, but they are not the same, and I need it all removed from all of these `.qc` files with a command

Comment: Is this a Javascript question or a shell scripting question? If the latter, are we talking windows (batch) or unix (bash)?

Comment: it's windows 7 batch file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `findstr /V` to exclude all lines containing a match (remove `/I` for case-sensitive searches):

```
@echo off
for /R "." %%F in ("*.qc") do (
    > "%%~F.tmp" findstr /V /I "^$hbox\>" "%%~F"
    > nul move /Y "%%~F.tmp" "%%~F"
)
```

This enumerates all `*.qc` files in the given directory (the current one here, `.`), and for each found file, copies all lines not beginning with the word `$hbox` to a temporary file, then moving this onto the original file (hence **overwriting** it; so place `rem` in front of the `move` command line for testing).

Comment: Thanx alot... allmost there but only one small problem... it works in same folder with .qc file,but not in subfolders... :\

Comment: Fixed -- see my [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40550307/2)...

Answer (score 0):

This batch file should do it. It loops through all subfolders and modifies all *.QC* files. Be **VERY** careful when testing it since it will rewrite your original QC files.

```dos
@ECHO OFF 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /r . %%a in (*.qc) do (
    set fname=%%a
    for /f "delims=" %%b in (!fname!) do (
        set oneline=%%b
        set keyword=!oneline:~0,5!
        if NOT !keyword!==$hbox echo %%b
    ) >> !fname!.qc2
    del !fname!
    move !fname!.qc2 !fname!>nul
)
```

Comment: Not working... do i need to change something in the script?